# C# LINQ DatabaseEntitie Query to first Value in Last Element results in Error

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have my Microsoft SQL 2008 Database Entity with one Table containing 6 Columns where the first column is simply my primarykey which is a number which gets increased each step.

I wrote a method which returns the next primary key (an integer)

```
private int NextPrimaryKey()
{
    int NextPrimaryKey;
    using (MitarbeiterlisteEntities entities = new MitarbeiterlisteEntities())
    {
        NextPrimaryKey = entities.Mitarbeiterliste.LastOrDefault().primaerschluessel;
        NextPrimaryKey++;
    }
    return NextPrimaryKey;
}
```

The Problem is, that I always get an error saying:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'IntraNET_Prototype.Mitarbeiterliste LastOrDefaultMitarbeiterliste' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

What's wrong? I simply just want to access the first value(column) in the last element which is primaerschluessel. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Last` and `LastOrDefault` is not supported in Linq-to-Entities.

You must use:

```
NextPrimaryKey = entities.Mitargeiterliste
                         .Select(e => e.primaerschluessel)
                         .OrderByDescending(p => p)
                         .FirstOrDefault();
```

=> you will first order entities in descending order and than select the first one.

Comment: Thanks! That works, just for my understanding. What does e => e.primaerschluessel and p => p mean?

Comment: The first part says that you want to select only primary key so the following query doesn't work with the entity but with list of primary keys so ordering is done directly on pk. It doesn't have to be written in this order. You can still work with the entity as you did but you must order it by key.